# Ejb with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ejb, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7

I am very new in Ejb and with very few knowledge about it. I have download NetBeans (7.01) and GlassFish and run a sample program. But, as I have no idea about Ejb, I can't understand how to run [this program](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/entity-bean-example.shtml) on NetBeans. Can anybody help me by giving steps how to run [this program](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/entity-bean-example.shtml). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans installs on default GlassFish web application server, which deploys your enterprise projects. To ensure that server is registered in the IDE, go to Services -> Servers inlay and look for "GlassFish Server 3.x". If you found it, open projects properties inlay: right click on your enterprise project -> Properties -> Run and make sure, that "Server" is set to "GlassFish Server 3.x". Then you can deploy you enterprise application: right click on project -> Deploy. IDE should start application server and deploy your application. To run your deployed project right click -> Run or type in the browser address, given in your tutorial, which is mapped to your resource (e.g. http://localhost:8080/book). In this way GlassFish doesn't require additional settings files except persistence.xml in your ejb project and web.xml in the web project.

In case you don't have GlassFish server installed, you can download it [here](http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html). Make sure you don't have it already installed separately from NetBeans.

If you want to deploy your app on JBoss application server (instead of GlassFish), you should first download it from [official site](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) and install. After you've done it, you can set it as server in NetBeans: Services -> Servers -> Add server. Then you can deploy your project as was described above.

Comment: Sorry Eadel, actually my this question is little bit confusing, so I add another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640336/ejb-code-with-netbeans-and-glassfish