# Ejb Code with NetBeans and GlassFish

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, glassfish-3

I am very new in Ejb and with very few knowledge about it. I have download NetBeans (7.01) and GlassFish (3.01). But, as I have no idea about Ejb, I am not getting how to run the code which includes a simple Statefull Session Bean, a jsp page and a back end database. For example, I found some example code like [this code](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/entity-bean-example.shtml) or many ["shopping cart"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbod.html)examples. Can any body help me by giving a step by step procedure how to run it . Or can anybody suggest a nice tutorial or book which shows step by step procedure along with code how to implement examples like those. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html), it uses Glassfish and Netbeans for creating a sample JEE6 application with EJBs.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Actually, I want little bit more elaborated example with code.

Comment: Well, the above tutorial offers a [link](http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples%252FJavaEE%252FNewsAppEE6.zip) with the source code

Comment: Okk. Thanks. I go through the code, but actually this code does not uses any Back End database like MySQOl, HSQL etc.

Comment: It actually does, one of the points in the tutorial teaches you how to create an Entity EJB that accesses JavaDB - the embedded database shipped with GlassFish. Using an external database would be a simple matter of configuring a different data source

Comment: >one of the points in the tutorial teaches you how to create an Entity EJB - Actually, it doesn't. It teaches how to to create a JPA Entity.